# How to make Window full screen in VisualStudio SkeletonBasics-D2D 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently using the SkeletonBasics-D2D library. I would like to give a presentation with the skeleton but need make the window fullscreen.  Here are the notes I currently worked through and my next step is potentially modifying the .rc file to work with the full screen windowed app; however, I'd like to ask first is anyone knows another way.

Potentially it could just be manipulating this code in my SkeletonBasics.rc file :

```
 IDD_APP DIALOGEX 0, 0, 512, 424
 STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CAPTION |     WS_SYSMENU
 EXSTYLE WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
 CAPTION "Skeleton Basics"
 CLASS "SkeletonBasicsAppDlgWndClass"
 FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
 BEGIN
     CONTROL         "",IDC_VIDEOVIEW,"Static",SS_BLACKFRAME,0,0,512,384
     LTEXT           "Click 'Seated' to change skeletal pipeline type!",IDC_STATUS,0,413,511,11,SS_SUNKEN,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
     CONTROL         "Seated",IDC_CHECK_SEATED,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX |  WS_TABSTOP,238,391,55,8
 END
```

Notes from code :

- creating a window causes different signals to be generated than a dialog
- where a dialog expects WM_INITDIALOG on create, a window should expect WM_NCCREATE
- the dialog's DLGPROC was being set with CreateDialogParamW(). The window's WNDPROC is set within a WNDCLASS structure and then registered before CreateWindow()
- the window's class name is important, as it's referred to in the SkeletonBasics.rc file wc.lpszClassName = L"SkeletonBasicsAppDlgWndClass";
- need to determine all messages sent to the window and handle them appropriately

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is a great example of full screen and have used it to convert my application into full screen.

To get there, I needed to change the dialog proc to a window.

http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-4