# Changing a Dialog to a Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, kinect-sdk

ok, so my problem is basically the same as in this post:
[How to make Window full screen in VisualStudio SkeletonBasics-D2D 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799118/how-to-make-window-full-screen-in-visualstudio-skeletonbasics-d2d-2013)

However i am not allowed to comment as my account is too new here. I tried asking in a Answer, which, although i apologized for doing so, instantly deleted.
As i have no other means of getting into contact with the answerer of that post, i now try to ask this question aswell.

What exactly do i have to do to achieve the conversion of the Dialogproc into a Window, as described in the other question?

Comment: As the previous answer.. [This link is very usefull.](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-4)

Comment: The thing is that i do not know how the previous answerer converted the DialogEx Dialog with all its contents to a window. I can not get it to work.
Can someone comment on the old topic and forward the answerer to this one? As i said, i myself am not allowed to comment.